# c2653 no class or namespace .hpp/.cpp

Tags: c++

Hey I'm a C++ beginner and trying to learn the basics. I tried to compile my code but it keeps telling me

> error. (c2653) "Framework": no class or namespace in line 4.

Another error is

> "sf":no class or namespace

but if I add `#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>` to my Framework.cpp code it solve the problem. As I understand the .hpp headers include all the code to the cpp files. So why should I include the SFML\Graphics.hpp twice?

Here is my Code:

```
#ifndef FRAMEWORKK_H

#define FRAMEWORKK_H

#include <iostream>
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include "stdafx.h"
class Framework
{
public:
    Framework();
    ~Framework();

void run();


private:

void quit();

void update();
void handleEvent();
void render();
sf::RenderWindow * pRenderWindow;
sf::Event  * pMainEvent;



bool mRun;
};#endif
```

and here is my .cpp code

```
#include "Frameworkk.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

Framework::Framework(){
    pRenderWindow = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), 
"Spiel");
    pMainEvent = new sf::Event;
    mRun = true;
}
Framework::~Framework()
{

}


void Framework::run()
{
    while (mRun)
    {
        update();
        handleEvent();
        render();

        quit();
    }
}

void Framework::quit()
{
    if (!mRun)
    {
        pRenderWindow->close();
    }
}


void Framework::update()
{

}





void Framework::handleEvent()
{
    while (pRenderWindow->pollEvent(*pMainEvent))
    {
        if (pMainEvent->type == sf::Event::Closed)
        {
            mRun = false;
        }
    }
}


void Framework::render()
{
    pRenderWindow->clear(sf::Color(120, 120, 120));
    pRenderWindow->display();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the file is called `Frameworkk .h` (With two `k`s)?

Comment: Remove `stdafx.h` from .h and `stdafx.h` must be included first before other includes in you .cpp.

Comment: omg thank you so much!  S.M.